# CS50 meal problem, Python 3, Error on decimal value return from convert() function

Tags: python-3.x, cs50

So we should prompt the user to input time as #:## a.m./p.m., the function convert should convert the inputted time to a float, return the float value and use print adequate text.

I'm receiving an Error stating that the convert function isn't returning a decimal value, but the terminal is passing all the tests, when I type in manually.

What's the issue?

```
def main():

    text = input("time here: ")
    time = convert(text) # call the function convert() and assign it to time variable, different from the one in the function
    print(time, type(time)) # check if the function returns a float value

    if 7 <= time <= 8: # simple logic for defining time
        print("breakfast time")
    elif 12 <= time <= 13:
        print("lunch time")
    elif 18 <= time <= 19:
        print("dinner time")
    elif time >= 24: # ensure that you can't type in number > 24
        print("Not a valid time point.")
    else:
        None # print None (null) for other cases

def convert(time):

    hour, minute, period = time.replace(":", " ").split(" ") # unpack the list with 3 arguments (3rd arugment is period = am/pm) and define floats
    hour = float(hour)
    minute = float(minute) / 60
    n_time = hour + minute # assign to a new variable n_time which should return float

    return round(n_time, 2) # return float, rounded to 2 decimals


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: *"Error stating that the convert function isn't returning a decimal value"*: that doesn't sound like a Python error. Where do you get this error from? Are you running this code on some website which has some framework and has its own set of error messages?

Comment: the code works perfectly fine for me.  the seperators are `:` or `space` and not `.`.

Comment: also, the variable `period` is never used.

Comment: 1. As per your first observation, pardon my inexperience, maybe my verbalization of the problem isn't on par with the technical syntax. I wanted to say that when I send my code to be checked, the first "Error" states: Expected value = some float number; Received value: Error :d

2. Yes, I'm aware. Should I always use the variables when defined in the function, even if they are there, just so I can extract some data, that doesn't need to be returned as a value of a function? 

Thanks for the feedback ( :

Answer (score 0):

As per the spec:

> Assume that the user’s input will be formatted in 24-hour time as #:## or ##:##

This line will error with that input:
`hour, minute, period = time.replace(":", " ").split(" ") # unpack the list with 3 arguments (3rd arugment is period = am/pm) and define floats`
errors

The Challenge says [emphasis added]:

> If up for a challenge, optionally add support for 12-hour times, allowing the user to input times in these formats **too**:
>
> #:## a.m. and ##:## a.m.
> #:## p.m. and ##:## p.m.

The Challenge  must handle *either* format.

Comment: Thank you for answering and giving your time.

But when type in the terminal either as 1:30 a.m. or 13:30 p.m. the terminal outputs the needed answer - mind you, using this line of code.

I don't understand how something can be valid in the terminal, and not valid when checked by the automated tester. Sorry I'm new. : d

Comment: check50 is not entering `1:30 a.m.`. It is entering `1:30`. The program does not handle the required format, which is `1:30`. Try it yourself just like the demo, no "a.m" or "p.m". It will give an error as described in the answer. That is what has to pass the checker. If you want to incorporate the challenge, the program must work with `1:30` AND `1:30 p.m.`.

Comment: Ah yes, I understand, I've made it exclusive to the a.m. p.m. input not for both inputs (if I'm correct). Thank you very much!